# Magento not rebuilding product image cache

Tags: magento

After clearing Magento's image cache, the site seems unable to rebuild image caches and certain pages are loading with a url extension ?___SID=U. All product images are coming up blank and look to be halting further loading of the site (no footer or sidebar loading on those pages).

It seems to be a permissions issue? Relevant folder (media) is currently recursively set to 777. But I'm still having issues.

Also renamed the htaccess in media to htaccess-old

No luck. Can't upload new images either. And no the server isn't out of storage.

Comment: Is this issue coming on your local machine? Is there such a case that when you upload a image with name like image.jpg then it should be creating such directory structure in media/catalog/product then i/m/image.jpg but stops after media/catalog/product/i/ , If yes then the user server is running on, do not have permission to set files and directories(which are created by server) on 777. Can you analyse you issue more closly and explain more here?

Comment: @DeependraSingh I have the exact issue you are describing, on my local machine (running osx + apache) the folder path gets created but the images are not there. Do you know how to solve that problem?

Comment: Same issue. Any solution found???

Answer (score 8):

Make sure PHP "GD" graphics module is installed. Magento uses it to create the thumbnails. Type in your shell:

```
php5 -m | grep gd
```

This should output a `gd` all by itself on a single line. If it does not, then you need to install the `gd` module.

Therefore, to install `gd`, type the following commands in the shell (tested on Ubuntu 12, but may vary depending on your OS):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Next, restart Apache. How to do that may be particular to your installation, so make sure that you know the right way to do it.

Ubuntu 12:

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

OS X:

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

If you don't need a "graceful" restart (preserves existing connections) then simply use the word "restart" instead of the word "graceful" in the above commands.

[There are more comprehensive instructions at this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/).

Answer (score 4):

- media folder permission 777
- deleted htaccess file under the media folder
- clear the cache
- cache folder is writeable
- rebuilt all indexes

try also:

```
cd /var/www/html/var
rm -rf cache/* full_page_cache/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Also in addition check if your GD library is installed with jpeg support.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg')) {
echo 'ok';
} else {
  echo 'jpeg support not installed';
}
?>
```

Comment: i am facing the same issues but gd lib is installed on plesk server